# concatenation of two or more base64 strings in python

Tags: python, base64, concatenation, encode

I'm tring to concatenate two strings encoded to base64 but it doesn't really work, just prints the first string in concatanation:

```
q = base64.b64encode("StringA")
print q # prints an encoded string
q = q+base64.b64encode("StringB")
print q # prints an encoded string

print base64.b64decode(q) # just prints "StringA"
```

Comment: why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: cause i need to concatenate the strings in different moments of the code

Comment: Okay... why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You are decoding a string that is concatenation of two base64 strings.  This is not correct.  You should do something like this -

```
base64.b64decode(base64.b64encode("StringA" + "StringB"))
```