# How can combine few base64 audio chunks (from microphone)

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, speech-to-text, microphone

I get base64 chunks from microphone.

I need to concatenate them and send to `Google API` as one `base64 string` for speech recognition. Roughly speaking, in the first chunk the word `Hello` is encoded, and in the second `world!`. I need to glue two chunks, send them to google api of one line and receive `Hello world!` in response

You can see `Google Speech-to-Text` as example. Google also sends data from the microphone in `base64 string` using websockets (see `Network`).

Unfortunately, I don't have a microphone at hand - I can't check it. And we must do it now.

Suppose I get

```
chunk1 = "TgvsdUvK ...."
chunk2 = "UZZxgh5V ...."
```

Do I understand correctly that it will be enough just

`base64.b64encode (chunk1 + chunk2))`

Or do you need to know something else? Unfortunately, everything depends on the lack of a microphone (

Comment: You've stated what you need, but not what you've done so far or need help with. You should provide that info or else this will probably be closed for needing more details/focus. For instance, does just using simple concatenation not work? Are you not sure how to even send any data over? Your post just lacks a lot of useful information.

Comment: @RandomDavis I just don't understand how to correctly concatenate two `base64 string` receiving from microphone... I don't know which information you need..

Comment: I'm not sure if you searched for other answers to this question or not, you didn't specify at all what you've researched. This looks just like what you're trying to do, did you just not see this or is there some reason it won't work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278521/concatenation-of-two-or-more-base64-strings-in-python

Comment: @RandomDavis Thnx. Ofc, I seen this answer. But I have little troubles. I updated my post. Sory(

Comment: Okay turns out that answer doesn't really apply. From what I've found you can't just concatenate the strings together and then send them all over, you'd have to decode everything to bytes, join the bytes, and then convert to a base64 string at the end. I'll see about writing that as an answer.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include code that loops through a list of input base64 strings, which is more in-line with what you'll need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example of encoding `chunk1 + chunk2` wouldn't work, since base64 strings have padding at the end. If you just concatenated two base64 strings together, they couldn't be decoded.

For example, the strings `StringA` and `StringB`, when their ascii or utf-8 representations are encoded in base64, are the following: `U3RyaW5nQQ==` and `U3RyaW5nQg==`. Each one of those can be decoded fine. But, if you concatenated them, your result would be `U3RyaW5nQQ==U3RyaW5nQg==`, which is invalid:

```
concatenated_b64_strings = 'U3RyaW5nQQ==U3RyaW5nQg=='
concatenated_b64_strings_bytes = concatenated_b64_strings.encode('ascii')
decoded_strings = base64.b64decode(concatenated_b64_strings_bytes)
print(decoded_strings.decode('ascii')) # just outputs 'StringA', which is incorrect
```

So, in order to take those two strings (which I'm using as an example in place of binary data) and concatenate them together, starting with only their base64 representations, you have to decode them:

```
import base64

string1_base64 = 'U3RyaW5nQQ=='
string2_base64 = 'U3RyaW5nQg=='

# need to convert the strings to bytes first in order to decode them
base64_string1_bytes = string1_base64.encode('ascii')
base64_string2_bytes = string2_base64.encode('ascii')

# now, decode them into the actual bytes the base64 represents
base64_string1_bytes_decoded = base64.decodebytes(base64_string1_bytes)
base64_string2_bytes_decoded = base64.decodebytes(base64_string2_bytes)

# combine the bytes together
combined_bytes = base64_string1_bytes_decoded + base64_string2_bytes_decoded

# now, encode these bytes as base64
combined_bytes_base64 = base64.encodebytes(combined_bytes)

# finally, decode these bytes so you're left with a base64 string:
combined_bytes_base64_string = combined_bytes_base64.decode('ascii')
print(combined_bytes_base64_string) # output: U3RyaW5nQVN0cmluZ0I=

# let's prove that it concatenated successfully (you wouldn't do this in your actual code)
base64_combinedstring_bytes = combined_bytes_base64_string.encode('ascii')
base64_combinedstring_bytes_decoded_bytes = base64.decodebytes(base64_combinedstring_bytes)
base64_combinedstring_bytes_decoded_string = base64_combinedstring_bytes_decoded_bytes.decode('ascii')
print(base64_combinedstring_bytes_decoded_string) # output: StringAStringB
```

In your case, you'd be combining more than just two input base64 strings, but the process is the same. Take all the strings, encode each one to `ascii` bytes, decode them via `base64.decodebytes()`, and then add them all together via the `+=` operator:

```
import base64

input_strings = ['U3RyaW5nQQ==', 'U3RyaW5nQg==']
input_strings_bytes = [input_string.encode('ascii') for input_string in input_strings]
input_strings_bytes_decoded = [base64.decodebytes(input_string_bytes) for input_string_bytes in input_strings_bytes]
combined_bytes = bytes()
for decoded in input_strings_bytes_decoded:
    combined_bytes += decoded
combined_bytes_base64 = base64.encodebytes(combined_bytes)
combined_bytes_base64_string = combined_bytes_base64.decode('ascii')
print(combined_bytes_base64_string) # output: U3RyaW5nQVN0cmluZ0I=
```